# Ceiling box has 2 black and white wires 1 ground 1 red

Tags: electrical, ceiling-fan

Ceiling box has 2 black and white wires 1 ground 1 red. two white and black is carrying power to another point. I am replacing fan with new remote fan. fan has only white and black and controller takes care of light and fan. I simply connected white to white and black to black and ground and left the red wire as its a dead end. but fan is not working. If I brake two black wire and join hot black to black I loose power at another point. not sure what is going on.

Comment: You've either got a multi-wire branch circuit or a three-way-switch. First post pictures of the ceiling box if possible. Second, let us know how many switches you could use to turn that ceiling fan on and off before you started replacing it. Third is this */2 Cable with an extra red wire, or is it */3 using the cables red wire? And finally, if you're familiar enough with using a multi-meter and own one, take us a read across black and red.

Comment: With the power off at the breaker, check the wires at the switch without undoing them.  Pictures of the wires at the ceiling box and switch will help.

Comment: Post pics of the "before" wiring and the "current" wiring.